# jQuery UI: model dialog 'close'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor

I have 2 Razor views where one is loading the other in a jQuery UI dialog. In the view that get loaded in the dialog; I am opening another jQuery UI dialog to display a message.

The objective is to close both the dialogs when message dialog `Cancel` button is clicked.

Razor code is as follows:

Main View

```
<button id="openModel" onclick="openModel()">

<div id="mainDialog" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function openModel() {
        $('#mainDialog').dialog({
            open: function () {
                // loading "the secondary view in the model dialog"
                // url: controller-action url to load the second view
                $(this).load('url'); 
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Dialog View

```
<button id="messageOpener">Verify</button>

<div id="messageDialog" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#messageOpener").click(function () {
            $("#messageDialog").dialog("open");
                return false;
        });

        $("#messageDialog").dialog({
            buttons: {
                Retry: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    // **** ?? must close both dialogs. ****
                }                
            },
            autoOpen: false,
        });
    });

</script>
```

I have tried following approaches to close the dialogs:

**Approach 01:**

```
$(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
```

**Approach 02:**

```
$(this).dialog("close");
$("#mainDialog").dialog("close");
```

**Approach 03:**

```
$(".ui-dialog:visible").find(".dialog").dialog("close");
```

But all above does not close the dialogs as expected instead produces the following JS error:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'
>   v.extend.error
>   (anonymous function)
>   v.extend.each
>   v.fn.v.each
>   e.fn.(anonymous function)
>   $.dialog.buttons.Cancel
>   r.click
>   v.event.dispatch
>   o.handle.u

Comment: what happens when you put `$("#mainDialog").dialog("close");` when message dialog is closed? approach 2 looks fine though

Comment: @vimalnath, thanks. Yes, `$("#mainDialog").dialog("close");` closes the **messageDialog** but not the **mainDialog** also it gives the same error.

Comment: Have you tried defining the modals ahead of time (ie var firstDialog = $("#messageDialog").dialog({autoOpen: false, ...}); Same goes with the second one and close them as you will since you have access to both of them at the same time.

Comment: Another approach is make the 2nd modal close automatically when the 1st modal closes. ie var firstModal = $('#mainDialog').dialog({close: function(){ /* close 2nd modal method call */}});

Comment: @DennisRongo, Thanks. Could you elaborate your first post with a more detailed code snippet. As per your second post: assume i understood you properly; no, **both** dialogs must close **only** when **Cancel** button is clicked, not necessarily when the last dialog closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-writing the code in the following way solve the problem..

**1. Main View**

```
<button id="openModel" onclick="openModel()">

<div id="mainDialog" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    var $modelDialog = $('#mainDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        open: function () {
            // loading "the secondary view in the model dialog"
            // url: controller-action url to load the second view
            $(this).load('url'); 
        }
    });

    function openModel() {
        $modelDialog.dialog('open');    
    }

    function closeModel() {
        $modelDialog.dialog('close');    
    }

</script>
```

**2. Dialog View**

```
<button id="messageOpener">Verify</button>

<div id="messageDialog" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    var $messageDialog;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#messageOpener").click(function () {
            $messageDialog.dialog("open");
                return false;
        });

        $messageDialog = $("#messageDialog").dialog({
            buttons: {
                Retry: function () {
                    $messageDialog.dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    // [!!]
                    $messageDialog.dialog("destroy");
                    closeModel();
                }                
            },
            autoOpen: false,
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach 2 looks fine , but you get that error cause the `mainDialog` modal is not opened when you try to close the `message` dialog. Also, function `openModel` is not getting called anywhere.

Comment: Thanks you. But `openModel()` function is called in `<button id="openModel" onclick="openModel()">` pls. refer the **Main View**. Further `messageDialog` **is** open though the `mainDialog`, thus the `mainDialog` **is** open when the `messageDialog` appear.